# Query not working for finding array of tags in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, closures

I am tring to run the following but not getting the expected behaviour.

```
var searchQuery = {
    'one' : oneQuery,
    'two' : twoQuery,
    'three' : threeQuery,
    'four' : fourQuery
};

for(query in searchQuery){
    var tags = ['text'];
    tags.push(query);
    SomeTable.update({ text : { $regex: searchQuery[query], $options: 'xi' }},
        {$addToSet: {tags: tags}}, {multi: true});

    SomeTable.find({ tags : tags })
        .exec(function(err, rows) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            console.log('Size of result for ' + query + ': ' + rows.length);
            for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                console.dir(rows[i].tags);
            }
        });
}
```

This prints:

```
Size of result for one: 1
["text,one"]
Size of result for one: 2
["text,two"]
["text,two"]
Size of result for one: 0
Size of result for one: 0
```

I have two question on this.

1. Follwing query returns empty.

   db.sometable.find(tags: 'text')

Also follwoing query doesnt works:

```
db.sometable.find(tags: ["text,one"])
```

And this doesnt work either:

```
db.snippets.find({ tags: {$all : ["text,one"]}})
```

I am expecting to tags array in my collection and find the document based on the tags list.

2. Is there a scope of using closure here. (PS i am new to javascript)

## Update

Here is one document from my collection:

```
{ _id: 23xagb6bo97203947005da61d,
  __v: 0,
  tags: [ 'text,one' ],
  value: '#text #one' }
```

## Update 2

Does mongodb support passing array as a field value? Or is something wrong with my code.

Comment: narrow it down with only mongo shell commands first. note that mongo will find an element within an array with no special treatment. ie. find({tags: "one"}). 
 if you're trying to find a complete match then use {$all : []} as you have. not sure what 'text' means. whats the expected document

Comment: 'text' is just another tag for a document. I have tried all combination that I knew both in mongo shell and nodejs.

Comment: can u print one record /  document

Comment: if the array name is text then .find({text: "one"})

Comment: i am updating the question with one document from my collection. And the array name is 'tags'. 'tags' array contain one element 'text' along with others.

Comment: I found the issue Gabe. Updated it as a answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little reading of mongodb $addToSet helped me figure out the issue here.

MongoDB docs for $addToSet says

> "If the value is an array, $addToSet appends the whole array as a
>   single element. To add each element of the value separately, use the
>   $each modifier with $addToSet."

So, using $each as follows worked here:

```
{$addToSet: {tags: {$each: tags}}}
```

I should have written the update statement as follows:

```
SomeTable.update({ text : { $regex: searchQuery[query], $options: 'xi' }},
        {$addToSet: {tags: {$each: tags}}}, {multi: true});
```

This will prevent MongoDB from appending values specified as array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all of the documents in your collection are, so I'll address why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing given just the sample document, calling my single-document collection `test`. `db.test.find({ "tags" : "text" })` doesn't match because the `tags` field of the sample document does not contain the value `"text"` in the array; it contains the value `"text,one"`, which is a different string. Perhaps you meant for the value of the tags array to be `["text", "one"]`, or you want to use [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)? The queries

```
db.test.find({ "text" : ["text, one"] })
```

and

```
db.test.find({ "text" : { "$all" : ["text, one"] } })
```

do match that sample document - I think you must have made some mistake.

Comment: I agree, something has gone wrong. I suspect, it might be because of using 'tags' array in update( ). But not sure.